# Function reference lost outside loop

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to play with interpolation with `scipy` and I've hit a bug that I think is unrelated to both `scipy` and `numpy`. Once I exit the loop where I insert my functions into a list, the functions in the list cease to exist. Here is my reduced example illustrating my problem.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


function_list = [ lambda x: np.sin(x), lambda x: -np.exp(x) ]

new_funcs = []
ea_func_steps = 100
x_points = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, ea_func_steps)

plt.figure()
# shift functions up 1 and interpolate
for f_i, func in enumerate(function_list):
    dest = func(x_points) + 1
    interp_res = interpolate.interp1d(x_points, dest)
    # fill the function list with the new functions for later use
    new_funcs.append(lambda x: interp_res(x))

    # print for verification
    print(new_funcs[f_i])
    # plot for verification
    plt.title("inside loop")
    plt.plot(new_funcs[f_i](x_points))

plt.figure()
for n_f in new_funcs:
    # print for verification
    # same ids!
    print(n_f)
    # plot for verification
    # this just plots the last function twice!
    plt.title("outside loop")
    plt.plot(n_f(x_points))

plt.show()
```

Here are the resulting plots:
[image: inside loop]

[image: outside loop]

These plots should be the same, but they're not! What's going on?

Comment: You don't need the lambda here: `new_funcs.append(lambda x: interp_res(x))` -- `interp_res` is already a function that takes one argument and returns the desired result.

Comment: @kindall okay, that fixes it.... Now to figure out why....

Comment: The reason it fixes it is that closures bind by name. All the `interp_res` references in the lambdas point to the same object, the last one you made.

Comment: @kindall that makes sense! I didn't think of the lambda as a closure. How do I get around this assuming I absolutely need to put the call inside the lambda (which is the case in my actual code)?

Comment: The usual method is to use a default argument value to capture the variable at the time the lambda is created. e.g. `lambda x, interp_res=interp_res: interp_res(x)`. Another way is to use a second function, say `make_lambda`, that accepts `interp_res` and returns the lambda function, and call that instead of defining the lambda directly.

Comment: @kindall if you post that as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Sure, glad to. Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need your lambda here:

```
new_funcs.append(lambda x: interp_res(x))
```

`interp_res` is *already* a function that takes one argument and returns the value you need. So you can just write:

```
new_funcs.append(interp_res)
```

The reason this fixes the problem is that the closure in the lambda binds `interp_res` by name, and all your lambdas thus end up with the same value of `interp_res` (the last one you defined).

The usual method of addressing this behavior of closures (and forcing the name to be bound at definition time) is the default argument value:

```
lambda x, interp_res=interp_res: interp_res(x)
```

Another way is to write a function that returns the lambda you want; the value in the closure is fixed when the function returns:

```
def makelambda(interp_res):
    return lambda x: interp_res(x)

# ...

new_funcs.append(make_lambda(interp_res))
```

Of course, you can also write the latter as a lambda:

```
new_funcs.append((lambda f: lambda x: f(x))(interp_res))
```